# ESXi 5: Disable software iSCSI from CLI

Tags: vmware-esxi, command-line-interface

I am having trouble with the management agents on my ESXi hosts, as they keep crashing/not responding..

I am suspecting my iSCSI storage, as it works a bit like the wind is blowing - and we have more or less migrated away from it.

So I am looking for a way to disable Software iSCSI from the CLI (I have SSH access to the hosts) to see if that helps.

I get this error when restarting the services:
`Not all VMFS volumes were updated; the error encountered was 'Timeout'.`
The VMs are still running, so the VMFS volumes it's talking about is the iSCSI ones - which are not in use right now.

Comment: Why not just unmount the iSCSI datastore and detach the iSCSI targets?

Comment: Because I have no access to the management services because they won't start properly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is:

`esxcfg-swiscsi -d`